# Regular expressions and preg_split()

Tags: php, regex

I have looked at several of the other regular expressions questions here and on other message boards. I am beating my head against the wall because I just can't seem to wrap my head around this. (or regular expressions in general)

I am pulling a time stamp from a MYSQL database. This is automatically generated, so it is formatted normally:  `2011-12-17 21:30:56`

I want to break this up into an array without having to use multiple explodes. I am assuming `preg_split()` is the answer here. If you have a better idea, I am all ears (though I feel like I need to figure out how to use regular expressions at some point anyway.)

In any case, I am trying to split this up at each "-" ":" and " ". After a bit of reading it seems like a character class is the answer, here is my code, that is simply not working:

```
$date_arr = preg_split("/ [- :] /", $order['order_date']);
```

This is outputting: `Array ( [0] => 2011-12-17 21:30:56 )`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This doesn't necessarily answer your question about regex, but have you thought about just using MySQL or the PHP `date()` function to separate out each date component, instead of using `preg_split()`?

Comment: That would be `strtotime()`. The problem with your regex is that it also looks for two spaces around the separator list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your [preg_split](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) fails is because of the spaces surrounding `[- :]`.

As it's currently written in will only split on `" - "`, `"   "` and `" : "`.

```
$date_arr = preg_split("/ [- :] /", ... ); // original
$date_arr = preg_split("/[- :]/", ...);    // fixed
```

---

Instead of using functions such as [`explode`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`preg_split`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split your string, use [`strtotime`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`getdate`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php):

```
print_r (
  getdate (strtotime ("2011-12-17 21:30:56"))
);
```

...

```
Array
(
    [seconds] => 56
    [minutes] => 30
    [hours] => 21
    [mday] => 17
    [wday] => 6
    [mon] => 12
    [year] => 2011
    [yday] => 350
    [weekday] => Saturday
    [month] => December
    [0] => 1324153856
)
```

Comment: I knew it had to be easier than I was making it. #facepalm,

Answer (score 1):

You have unncesary spaces in regex. Try this:

```
preg_split("/[- :]/", '2011-12-17 21:30:56');
```